# How to debug Azure pipeline stage/job condition returning true when expecting false

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I was setting up a condition to skip tests run for pipeline development purposes by setting variable `skipTestsOnFeatureBranchName` to current branch name. I could then leave it in place when ready to merge to master and have the tests still enabled on master.

I did not get it working right away though as I had one of the conditions backwards. Since I have had lots of trouble with variable syntax (and also had here initially as in conditions you cannot have dollar sign character used in elsewhere for all the condition syntax '$').

It seems that condition and all related variables are only expanded if the condition evaluates to `false`. *So how should I go about debugging condition that evaluates to `true`, but I want it to be `false`?*

[image: Expanded condition when condition evaluates to false and job is skipped]
**Image 1. Expanded condition when condition evaluates to false and job is skipped**

[image: Image 2. Condition is not expanded to output even when system diagnostics flag is enabled for the build.]
**Image 2. Condition is not expanded to output even when system diagnostics flag is enabled for the build.**

I had quite a git commit amend and force push spree to get this one working, but here is the version that works as I expect (skips the job when branch defined by `skipTestsOnFeatureBranchName` matches `branchPath`):

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - feature/*

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  fullBranchPath: $[variables['Build.SourceBranch']]  
  branchPath: $[replace(variables['fullBranchPath'],'refs/heads/', '')]  
  isMasterBranch: $[eq(variables['fullBranchPath'], 'refs/heads/master')]
  skipTestsOnFeatureBranchName: 'feature/skip_stage_on_branch'

stages:
  - stage:
    displayName: 'Stage to skip'
    jobs:
      - job:
        displayName: 'Job to skip'
        condition: or(eq(variables['isMasterBranch'], 'true'), and(eq(variables['isMasterBranch'], 'false'), ne(variables['branchPath'], variables['skipTestsOnFeatureBranchName'])))
        steps:
        - script: echo Hello, world!
          displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

The problem I had was that was with the last comparison in the condition having `eq` and not `ne`, so having all the variables logged would have surely help me arrive to the solution earlier. Maybe I should have just setup job variables and log them, but still I could have doubted if the [condition syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) is correct as it differs from [all other variable syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax):

```
diff --git a/azure-pipelines-test-condition.yml b/azure-pipelines-test-condition.yml
index cd28c33..d1f86d1 100644
--- a/azure-pipelines-test-condition.yml
+++ b/azure-pipelines-test-condition.yml
@@ -24,7 +24,7 @@ stages:
     jobs:
       - job:
         displayName: 'Job to skip'
-        condition: or(eq(variables['isMasterBranch'], 'true'), and(eq(variables['isMasterBranch'], 'false'), eq(variables['branchPath'], variables['skipTestsOnFeatureBranchName'])))
+        condition: or(eq(variables['isMasterBranch'], 'true'), and(eq(variables['isMasterBranch'], 'false'), ne(variables['branchPath'], variables['skipTestsOnFeatureBranchName'])))
         steps:
         - script: echo Hello, world!
           displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

Comment: Can you explain "cannot have dollar sign used in elsewhere condition syntax"? Here's an example of how I use variables in conditions. `eq(${{ parameters.isMasterBranch }}, True)`

Comment: Have you downloaded the expanded yaml logs from a deployment?

Comment: Yes, so I tested different sytaxes, but actually missed that this time I could have likely picked that [template expression syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#template-expression-syntax).

Comment: Anyways this is the error I got with runtime expression syntax. So why is '$' a unrecognized value? I did also try macro syntax and got similar error:
> An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. Unrecognized value: '$'. Located at position 7 within expression: or(eq($[variables['isMasterBranch']], 'true'), and(eq($[variables['isMasterBranch']], 'false'), eq($[variables['branchPath']], $[variables['skipTestsOnFeatureBranchName']]))). For more help, refer to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=842996